# C++ autoload default constructor on object property

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm new in C++ programming and I have the problem that the `WorldMapState` class automatically creates a new object of the property `tile_map (TileMap)`. If TileMap has no arguments on constructor there is no problem, but I added three arguments and WorldMapState automatically tries to create an object with empty constructor. Why C++ works in that way? How can I solve the problem?

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

namespace SaGa {

    class TileMap : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable
    {
    public:
        TileMap(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, unsigned int tileSize);
        bool load(const std::string& tileset, sf::Vector2u tileSize, const int* tiles);
        void setSprite(unsigned int value, unsigned int x, unsigned int y);
    private:
        virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;

        sf::VertexArray m_vertices;
        sf::Texture m_tileset;

        unsigned int _width;
        unsigned int _height;
        unsigned int _tileSize;
    };
}
```

Main Class

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include "State.hpp"
#include "Game.hpp"
#include "TileMap.hpp"
#include <vector>

namespace SaGa
{
    class WorldMapState : public State
    {
    public:
        WorldMapState(GameDataRef data);

        void Init();
        void HandleInput();
        void Update(float dt);
        void Draw(float dt);

    private:
        GameDataRef _data;
        //sf::Texture _tilemap;
        //std::vector<sf::Sprite> _tiles;
        TileMap _tilemap;
    };
}
```

Comment: If you want to construct `TileMap` object using constructor taking 3 parameters then you need to invoke that constructor passing those 3 parameters... `WorldMapState(GameDataRef data) : _tilemap{param1, param2, param3} ...`

Comment: `TileMap() = delete` ?

Comment: So if I not pass a constructor it creates automatically, but if I pass a constructor it will not create the object?

Comment: If you don't initialize `_tilemap` explicitly then it will be initialized by compiler by invoking constructor taking no arguments. Unless you provide those 3 arguments into constructor they aren't going to magically get there.

Answer (score 2):

> If TileMap has no arguments on constructor there is no problem, but I added three arguments and WorldMapState automatically tries to create an object with empty constructor. Why C++ works in that way?

Because your `TileMap` constructor needs 3 parameters. They're not optional. Either add another constructor to `TileMap` that takes no arguments:

```
public:
    TileMap();
    TileMap(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, unsigned int tileSize);
```

Or use default values for the existing constuctor:

```
public:
    TileMap(unsigned int width = 0, unsigned int height = 0, unsigned int tileSize = 0);
```

Or initialize `_tilemap` correctly by using 3 parameters using either inline initialization:

```
private:
    // ...
    TileMap _tilemap{0, 0, 0};
```

Or using a constructor initializer list in the constructor's definition in the cpp file:

```
WorldMapState::WorldMapState(GameDataRef data)
    : _tilemap(0, 0, 0)
{
    // ...
}
```

Pass values that are suitable in your case, of course.

Comment: If in the code I put TileMap _tilemap(1,2,3), it references to private property or a new variable inside the function

Comment: @albert "New variable inside the function"? What function? Also note, it's not `TileMap _tilemap(1,2,3)`. It's `TileMap _tilemap{1,2,3}`.

Comment: Inside of the constructor of WorldMapState all call the constructor of TileMap

Comment: @albert In that case, use a constructor initializer list. I updated the answer.

Comment: That worked! It is a strange way to code. I usually work with Java, but I want to learn C++

Comment: @albert It's not strange. Just different :-)